# Calculating a shadow length and angle based on the X/Y offsets

Tags: javascript, typescript, math, calculation, angle

I am working on parsing data from file generated by a program, it can apply a shadow to text.  In the UI you simply set an angle, length, and radius

[image: UI]

With those values shown in the screenshot, that data is saved like this inside of an XML node

```txt
10|{1.41421356237309, -1.4142135623731}
```

The format is:

```txt
radius|{offsetX, offsetY}
```

I'd like to calculate these values back into the angle and length so I can return them in my parser.  Looking around online I have only found the opposite: a way to calculate those offsets from the angle and length.

```js
let length = 2;
let angle = 135;
let shadowX = Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * length;
let shadowY = Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * length;

console.log(shadowX, shadowY); //1.4142135623730951 -1.414213562373095
```

This is where I wish I'd paid more attention in my algebra classes. I have no idea how to proceed here to calculate the values I want.  I need to be able to input those X/Y offset values and get the angle and length returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2#description)

> The Math.atan2() method measures the counterclockwise angle θ, in radians, between the positive x-axis and the point (x, y).

[Math.hypot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot)

> Calculating the hypotenuse of a right triangle, or the magnitude of a complex number, uses the formula Math.sqrt(v1*v1 + v2*v2), where v1 and v2 are the lengths of the triangle's legs, or the complex number's real and complex components.

```js
let length = 2;
let angle = 135;
let shadowX = Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * length;
let shadowY = Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180)) * length;

console.log('angle', Math.atan2(shadowX, shadowY) * 180 / Math.PI)
console.log('length', Math.hypot(shadowX, shadowY))
```

Note:

I used `Math.atan2` backwards (y should be first, x second), because you have your `shadowX` and `shadowY` variables misnamed. Usually `cos` is used to calculate `x` component and `sin` is used to calculate `y` component

Comment: It's interesting that you mention the `atan2` function takes `y` first because Using the values from my `{1.41421356237309, -1.4142135623731}` string works when I use them in this order. So perhaps I was just assuming they were in `{x, y}` format because they must be in `{y,x}` format!